# Injecting services into an Angular2 component doesn't work

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build an Angular starter kit but am having trouble injecting a service into a component.

Here's my main file `app.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'es6-shim';

import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import { MyService } from './services/sampleService';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  bindings: [MyService]
})
@View({
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li>{{ appStatus }}</li>
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
class MyAppComponent {
  appStatus: string;
  message: string;

  constructor(myService: MyService) {
    this.message = myService.getMessage();
    this.appStatus = 'Application is working.';
  }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

And my service:

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/angular2';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  message: string;

  constructor() {
    this.message = "Services are working";
  }

  getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }

}
```

As I understand it (from reviewing other Angular2 samples), this is the way to go; however, the second I add `myService: MyService` and its usage into the `MyAppComponent`, the app doesn't load up. No error is thrown at runtime and there are no errors at compile time either.

I've also tried removing `@Injectable` from `MyService` class but it made no difference. It still doesn't load up. I've had no issue injecting components into the view so at least that works.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to say, personally I can't see anything wrong. Could you reproduce this in a plnkr? Or a github repo?

Comment: https://github.com/AntJanus/angular2-ts-starter-kit heres the repo. Thanks!

Comment: TBH I don't know what it could be. But for what I see you are using webpack, [here's a repo](https://github.com/angular-class/angular2-webpack-starter) working with webpack and the latest ng2 version (a39)

Comment: Yeah, I checked there too but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @EricMartinez it turns out the problem was with TypeScript compilation. I forgot to add the option for "emitDecoratorMetadata" which handles DI I guess.

Comment: modify bindings: [MyService]  with viewBindings[MyService]

Comment: You need to pass a providers options to the component annotation: @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [MyService]
})